# grep lines contain exact string in a file

Tags: bash, grep, lines

I have a file include many lines
I want to grep lines contain a string using a variable, which this string is a uri like:

`/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`

I want to grep only lines contain exact uri:

`/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`

and do not extract lines like this:

`/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?blahblah`

Example File:

```
4.2.2.4 sitename.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
4.2.2.4 sitename.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?
4.2.2.4 sitename.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?blah
4.2.2.4 sitename.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?blahblah
```

Search subject:

```
sitename.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
```

Should extract lines like this:

```
4.2.2.4 sitename.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `-F` option to grep to tell it to use strings instead of regexps and `-x` to mach whole lines:

```
grep -x -F "$variable"
```

See the man page.

Given your updated question:

```
$ awk -v tgt='sitename.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' '$NF==tgt' file
4.2.2.4 sitename.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
```

Comment: I don't want to match whole line, the search string is part of line, but I want to extract whole line

Comment: And also the search string should be exact, means 'search' should not extract 'searching'

Comment: I just updated my answer given your updated question.

Comment: Great, your awk solved my problem, Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]; next} $1 in a' pattern.txt data_file.txt
```

Assuming that you keep your data in the `data_file.txt` like:

```
www.sitename.com/admin/index.php
www.sitename.com/admin
www.sitename.com/
...
```

And the stuff that you want to identify in another file, e.g. `pattern.txt` like:

```
www.sitename.com/admin
```

Comment: I used your code as a piped:

| awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]; next} $1 in a' $variable

not worked

Comment: Oh, okay. Then it's even easier: `| awk -vvar=$variable '$0==var'`

Comment: Not leaving a space between `-v` and `var=` makes your code unnecessarily gawk-specific. Just leave a space: `awk -v var="$variable" '$0==var' file`. And remember to always quote your shell variables of course.

Comment: not lucky, the search string is : `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` , can you test a sample?

Comment: It works for me. Are you sure that the entry is existed in the file? Also, this code matches literally the exact entry. So, make sure that there is nothing more than `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` in the line. Any extra spaces, tabs etc. e.g. at the end will cause a non-match.

Comment: If you don't want to match the whole line (as you said in another comment) use `~` instead of `==`. a.k.a: `| awk -v var="$variable" '$0 ~ var'`

Comment: @Tasos no, you can't do a regexp match or you'd have to escape all the RE metacharacters otherwise, for example, `a.c` would match `abc`. You'd also have to introduce word delimiters or similar to bound the regexps. Until the OP posts realistic sample input/output we're just guessing at what he needs anyway though.

Comment: So what should I to do? I edited the question please check it

Comment: `cat data_file.txt | awk -v var="$variable" '$NF==var'`

Comment: That would be a [UUOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat), awk is perfectly capable of opening files.

Comment: I just placed it there since he commented earlier that he pipelines his data to the awk command.